# Probability: pairs of Shoes problem

Tags: probability

Given n different pair of shoes,a total of 2n shoes,we put these 2n shoes together and randomly divided into n groups,with each group having 2 shoes.If 2 shoes in a group are just a pair,them we call this group the "pair group".Let X be the number of "pair groups".Calculate the expectation of x.

> For this problem,I figured out that 2n shoes divided into n groups that has $C{2 \choose 2n}$ * $C{2 \choose 2n-2}$*... * $C{2 \choose 2}$ and the probability of X = n is $ \frac{2^n*n!}{2n!} $
> X can be 0,1,2,...,n.So what is the probability of X = 0,X = 1,...,X=n-1,and how to calculate the E(X)?

Comment: @Phicar Confused about it.Can you explain it explicitly?

Comment: $C\binom{k}{n}$ to count the number of subsets of size $k$ from a set with $n$ elements?  That's a new notation for me... I strongly recommend using the far more standard $\binom{n}{k}$ instead.

Comment: As for derangements @Phicar no, that is incorrect.  That assumes that in each group we have exactly one left shoe and exactly one right shoe.  This was not stated in the problem and so we may not assume it.  Instead, I interpret the problem as you could possibly have a left shoe of type A as well as a left shoe of type B in a group.

Comment: As for calculating... finding the actual pdf and the probability that $X=k$ for arbitrary $k$...  this is completely unnecessary and only slows your progress on the problem down.  It is a rather involved difficult question which does not appear at all in the recommended approach to the problem.  Approach instead by linearity of expectation.  Ask yourself what the probability that the left shoe of type A is in a group with the right shoe of type A.  Repeat for each left shoe of each shoetype.  Your answer will be the sum of these probabilties.

Comment: @Phicar My mother would have insisted that shoes of the same type stay together at all times... if we're getting into how people organize their shoeclosets then we have left mathematics behind.  This is meant to be a hypothetical scenario which doesn't necessarily match common human behavior.  Or are you saying that your mother would disagree with my math skills?

Comment: @JMoravitz You are right. I delete my comments. Thanks! It was meant to be a joke on my vision of why they should be the same shoe. No harm meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approaching the problem by Linearity of Expectation -

First to find, probability of a group of two shoes be a pair -

The number of ways to arrange $2n$ shoes into $n$ groups of two $= \displaystyle \frac{(2n)!}{2^n} \times \frac{1}{n!}$

(which comes from ${2n \choose 2} {2n-2 \choose 2} ...{4 \choose 2}$ and we divide by $n!$ to account for overcounting).

If a group is a pair, the number of ways to arrange $(2n-2)$ remaining shoes into $(n-1)$ groups of two

$= \displaystyle \frac{(2n-2)!}{2^{(n-1)}} \times \frac{1}{(n-1)!}$

So the probability of a group being a pair $P(X_1) = \displaystyle \frac{ 1}{2n-1}$ (which makes sense as we are choosing one particular shoe from $(2n-1)$ to make a pair).

To find expected number of pairs, we will sum their individual expected values.

So expected number of pairs, $E(\mathbb{X}) = P(X_1) \times 1 + P(X_2) \times 1 + ... + P(X_n) \times 1 = \displaystyle \frac{n}{2n-1}$